# MacBook Pro 5,1 will only turn on after SMC reset

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hardware, power-management

Resetting the SMC every time the machine is turned off is the only way to turn it back on and when it is on the fans run at max speed etc. etc. (SMC issues).

- Have tried to swap out HDD and RAM. Software is current at Mavericks will all updates installed.
- Have tried to manually reinstall the SMC firmware but the system says that is not needed or something to that effect.

Anyone have any ideas what this could be or how I can install the SMC file anyways (bypassing the error that it isn't needed)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried giving the MacBook a PRAM reset? With the firmware password turned off hold down <kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, turn the computer on and wait for it to restart and you hear the start up chime before you let go.